# Allow only some devices to Sonos speakers (Unifi system)

Tags: sonos

We have 2 Sonos speakers on the same Wifi (ruled by a Unifi rooter)

We would like to be able to allow / forbid some devices to connect to those speakers. As Sonos doesn’t provide any built-in solution for this kind of need, is it possible to handle this with Unifi systems ?

Using 2 different networks could fix this, yet it doesn't answer some business requirements.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your speakers are in the same network, your Unifi router cannot do anything about it. In the same network you can reach all devices.

Placing the sonos speakers in a different network would allow you to do just that, but then the default app cannot find the speakers and you would still have trouble connecting to the speakers.

Because the default app uses SSDP (multicast device discovery protocol), without any extra configuration on the router, you won't be able to find the speaker IP when your device is in an other network then the sonos speakers.

Network A: All your wifi devices
Network B: All your sonos speakers

If your phone is on network B when starting the app, it discovers the speakers. If you then connect to Network A without restarting the app, you can still control the speakers, if devices from network A are allowed to connect to network B.

But if your phone is on network A while starting the application, it won't find the speakers because the sonos (by default) sends out multicast packages with a TTL of 1 (which means no extra hops).

Ps. I'm the author of a [sonos library](https://svrooij.io/node-sonos-ts/) to control your devices from a node application.

Comment: "but then the default app cannot find the speakers and you would still have trouble connecting to the speakers."
If this is the solution we choose, can't we just connect to each network and configure the speakers from the default app separately ? 
Which troubles do you think we can get ?